# How do i remove custom extension from azure scale set in Powershell

Tags: azure-vm-scale-set

How do I remove custom script extension from a Azure scale set using powershell. the below script runs without any error but the extension is till there. Is something still missing?

```
# Get information about the scale set
$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss `
                -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup `
                -VMScaleSetName $ScaleSet

Remove-AzureRmVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -Name "customScript"
Update-AzureRmVmssInstance -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -VMScaleSetName $scaleSetName -InstanceId "*"
```

Comment: Is wildcard for instance ID supported? I do not see it in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.compute/update-azurermvmssinstance?view=azurermps-5.7.0. Also how do you determine that extension is still there?

Comment: Please try running Update-AzureRmVmss after Remove-AzureRmVmssExtension and before Update-AzureRmVmssInstance

Answer (score 0):

$vmss = Get-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $RGName -VMScaleSetName $vmssName

Remove-AzureRmVmssExtension -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss -Name $vmssExtensionName

Update-AzureRmVmss -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $vmssName -VirtualMachineScaleSet $vmss

Comment: Could you, please, format the commands as code to improve on readability?

Comment: try adding an explanation to your answer. please look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for help.